# HOsted XMPP Service with HTTP Developer APIs

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmpp, chat, instant-messaging

Is there any services out there that supports XMPP Server with a developer API that allows xml/json http request to send/receive IMs?

I am trying to build a web chat system that connects to my jaber/xmpp IM client. What I am trying to do is integrate what I currently have in operation for my company but add web chatting.

http://www.olark.com/ provides everything I want as far as features however I want to build my own client interface/architecture since Olark's pricing gets expensive on the scale I plan to role this out in my company.

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful!

oh and on a side note, I am using pusher.com to run my web chatting and it works flawlessly. The problem is that I want to connect pusher's websockets into my current xmpp/jaber network.